# PHP & MySQL vote count problem?

Tags: php, mysql

I found this script on about.com which I'm trying to learn from on how to create a rating system but the script for some reason wont count a vote when the link is clicked and just reloads the page.

I was wondering how can I fix this problem? And what part of the code do I need to change and where?

Here is the full script below.

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sitename") or die(mysql_error());

//We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
if ( $mode=="vote") {

  //If the user has already voted on the particular thing, we do not allow them to vote again $cookie = "Mysite$id";
  if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) {
     echo "Sorry You have already ranked that site <p>";
  } else {
        //Otherwise, we set a cooking telling us they have now voted
    $month = 2592000 + time();
    setcookie(Mysite.$id, Voted, $month);

    //Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating
    mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total = total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id");
    echo "Your vote has been cast <p>";
  }
} 

//Puts SQL Data into an array
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vote") or die(mysql_error());

//Now we loop through all the data
while($ratings = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {

  //This outputs the sites name
  echo "Name: " .$ratings['name']."<br>";

  //This calculates the sites ranking and then outputs it - rounded to 1 decimal
  if($ratings['total'] > 0 && $ratings['votes'] > 0) {
    $current = $ratings['total'] / $ratings['votes'];
  } else {
    $current = 0;
  }

  echo "Current Rating: " . round($current, 1) . "<br>";

  //This creates 5 links to vote a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rating for each particular item
  echo "Rank Me: ";
  echo "<a href=?mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 1</a> | ";
  echo "<a href=?mode=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 2</a> | ";
  echo "<a href=?mode=vote&voted=3&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 3</a> | ";
  echo "<a href=?mode=vote&voted=4&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 4</a> | ";
  echo "<a href=?mode=vote&voted=5&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 5</a><p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You get a vote down for abusing this site, you already pasted this code once, an hour before you created this question.  If you want to change some details of your question, edit the original question, DO NOT ask a new one, you're just repeating yourself.

Answer (score 3):

`$mode` is never set? While it may have worked if [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) was on, it is not on by default any more (and is removed in later versions of PHP)

```
//We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
if ( $mode=="vote") {
```

Maybe you mean

```
if ( $_GET['mode']=="vote") {
```

The same goes for `$id` and `$voted`, which are also never set.

**EDIT**
I also would like to add, that if I went and changed id to `1';DROP TABLE vote;` You would have a whole lot of data lost. Look at [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)

**EDIT**
If the row in the table doesn't exist, you will need to INSERT it before you can UPDATE it.

Comment: It won't count the vote. It just says Your vote has been cast.

Comment: So are you saying that about.com is a poor rating script. Is there a better tutorial out there to learn about how to create a rating script?

Answer (score -2):

I can also see $cookie is never set, looking at the code it should be **'Mysite' . $id**.  I added quotes for the string, though PHP will treat any unquoted text as string but avoid misunderstanding and errors later, its always a good idea.

Also this script assumes PHP option register_globals is on, you need to make that register_globals = ON in your php.ini

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER turn on register_globals, somebody should take away your server for even suggesting this.